# ClickableSpan doesn't work in Talkback mode when the text is long

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback, clickablespan

I have a simple demo app, where I use `ClickableSpan` to make a specific text as clickable. I works well when Talkback is OFF, of course.

But when Talkback is ON,

- If I use `rawText = shortRawText`, it works fine
- If I use `rawText = longRawText`, 10 characters longer, then the onClick doesn't work

I've researched to fix it but can't find a solution for it (someone suggest to create separated TextViews for non-clickable and clickable space, but I think it's complex and not efficient).

Maybe anyone is interesting in or already met that issue can help me on this.

Video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXnddfva34c

MainActivity.Kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val START_CLICK_LABEL = "{start_link}"
        const val END_CLICK_LABEL = "{end_link}"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val shortRawText = "For more details {start_link}terms and conditions{end_link}"
        val longRawText = "For more details, read our {start_link}terms and conditions{end_link}"

        val rawText = longRawText
        val linkText = rawText
            .substringAfter(START_CLICK_LABEL)
            .substringBefore(END_CLICK_LABEL)

        val spannableString = SpannableString(
            rawText.replace(Regex.fromLiteral(START_CLICK_LABEL), "")
                .replace(Regex.fromLiteral(END_CLICK_LABEL), "")
        )

        val linkColor = Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)

        val matcher: Matcher = Pattern.compile(linkText).matcher(spannableString)
        if (matcher.find()) {
            spannableString.setSpan(
                object : ClickableSpan() {
                    override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                        Log.d("HiepMT", "onClick() is called!")
                    }

                    override fun updateDrawState(textPaint: TextPaint) {
                        textPaint.color = linkColor
                        textPaint.isUnderlineText = false
                    }
                },
                matcher.start(),
                matcher.start() + linkText.length,
                Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
        }

        // Set the movement method of the TextView to LinkMovementMethod
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()

        // Set the text of the TextView to the SpannableString object
        textView.text = spannableString
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```